# Load page Ajax and then slide it into page OR plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, slider

My site structure is more or less this:
HOME - PAGE1 - PAGE2 - PAGE3. 
What I would realize is a site with transition like "a mobile app" between pages, where you click on a button then the new page slide in. 
Now I'm looking on how to realize that, if using AJAX (that load the page and slide it but I don't know AJAX) or use a plugin (but I can't find anything). 
Another alternative is create a single page and then moving into that (would be great find a plugin to do that) but the pages are big so my site will became heavy. 
Does anyone have an idea how help me?
Thanks guys!

ps: the site is developed ONLY for tablet and smartphones

Comment: there are lots of tutorials on single page apps .. let google be your friend

Comment: @charlietfl I've searched a lot but I didn't find a good one, do you have a good link?

Comment: @robert, give me a few minutes ill write you a nice example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways to implement what you wanted, below i will show you one of them. (example at the bottom of the answer)

you hide the content outside of the screen, and slide it when page loads:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content_div">
    <p class="title">HOME</p>
    <a href="" class="nav">page 1</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.content_div {
    box-shadow:0 0 10px;
    border:10px solid black;
    height:800px;
    left:-1000px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-animation:slide_in 800ms ease-out forwards;
    position:absolute;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.title{
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav{
    margin-left:20px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide_in{
    0% {
        left:-1000px;
    }
    100% {
        left:0px;
    }
}
```

now when you click a link, you intercept the click using a custom handler, prevent the default redirection, execute a "slide out" animation and once the animation is done, you redirect manually:

the function inside `.promise().done()` will be executed as soon as all animations on the object are done:

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav").on("click",function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();        
        $(".content_div").animate({
            "margin-left":$(".content_div").width() +100
        }).promise().done(function(){
            window.location="http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/27o989vy/embedded/result/";
        });
    });
});
```

here is a <kbd>**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/hs62z0o8/embedded/result/)**</kbd>

implement this on every page in your website, and you should have sliding transitions.
change the transitions if you would like a different animation.

**NOTE:** in jsfiddle it will be a bit messed up because it will open itself inside itself, but on your website it will work as needed.

**UPDATE FOR AJAX:**

if you would like to avoid the disappearing of pages while window relocates to a new page, you need to load the content from the new page dynamically instead of changing location.

you can do that using plain ajax, or you can use jQuery's ajax extension `.load()`, it does the same ajax behind the scenes:

```
$(".nav_waitforajax").on("click", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(".content_div").animate({
        "margin-left": $(".content_div").width() + 100
    }).promise().done(function () {
        $(".content_div").load("/three", function () {
            $(".content_div").animate({
                "margin-left": 0
            });
        });
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**Ajax Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/occfnc0r/)</kbd>

**UPDATE 2:** delegated handlers for dynamic content:

```
//monitors a `mouseover` event on every element inside `.content_div`
//which fits the selector of "*" (everything)
$(".content_div").on("mouseover","*",function(){
    $(this).css({
        "background":"red"
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**Delegates Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/occfnc0r/2/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the tip,it works some events like click, hover etc but is there a way to run any kind of code after the ajax call? 
Another example, modify the css without any event (not on hover, not on click, just modify it)? Like "get the width of #div1 and set the width of #div2 = #div1

Comment: Yes of course, you do everything in the `.done()` function. After the content has been loaded, you select its elements as usual using jQuery or even vanilla javascript.

Comment: something like that? (I'm sorry for the several questions but ajax is completely new for me :O ) http://jsfiddle.net/srm6qxqz/

Comment: btw, I really don't understand this stuff.. try to think about a page (example.html) and think that I wrote more than 200 lines of code on that, if I'll put them inside the `.done()` makes my code a mess. I think that I should be a smarter idea, isn't it? Something like refresh the js file after the ajax call.

Comment: no worries :) feel free to ask whatever you need. and yes, exactly like in your fiddle. there is no need however to write all of the 200 lines in that function directly, you could add a new JS file with all the neede code in side a function, and in the `.done()` simply call that function from the separate js file. or alternatively, you could write the code in the new js file directly without a function, and just link it to your project after the loading in the Done function. there are plenty of examples about linking resources dynamically :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/srm6qxqz/2/ I tried to insert a function, and with an alert it works, but with `.css()` doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: thats because you misunderstood how it works :) the `.promise().done()` executes when the jQuery animations on the object are done. i assume you attach classes with css keyframes, better do the animation using jquery as i showed. regarding the .`load()`, it accepts 2 arguments: `.load( <Url to load> , <done function> )`. you need to run your code in the done function like [This](http://jsfiddle.net/srm6qxqz/3/)

Comment: shame on me, I didn't think to use it in a callback :O
btw, really thanks Banana, you made my day!
Can I have your email o something else so I'll show the project when is done :)

Comment: Btw, since ajax grab datas from others pages into the current, I stay all the time on the same page, therefore the "back" button obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to solve that? 
[Here](http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/) is what I'm talking about more or less, that change the page with an animation but the "back" button still work (because change the entire page). I tried it but I wasn't able to use it :/

Comment: hmm... if im not mistaken, there was a technique with location hashing, to append a hash with a name to the site url each time you load a new ajax, im not sure but its supposed to make the browser cache the page so you could use back button, not sure. you should look into it.

Comment: After two days of efforts I found what I really need, it's `jQuery Mobile`. I'm gonna use it, because makes the exacts behavior of what I wanna do. 
Btw, I would say to you that I really appreciate the time you dedicate to me :)

Comment: Glad you found what you were looking for :)